# how to make argsort result to be random between equal values?

Tags: python, sorting, random, numpy

Say you have a `numpy` vector `[0,3,1,1,1]` and you run `argsort`
you will get `[0,2,3,4,1]` but all the ones are the same!
What I want is an efficient way to shuffle indices of identical values.
Any idea how to do that without a while loop with two indices on the sorted vector?

```
numpy.array([0,3,1,1,1]).argsort()
```

Answer (score 14):

Use `lexsort`:
`np.lexsort((b,a))` means Sort by `a`, then by `b`

```
>>> a
array([0, 3, 1, 1, 1])
>>> b=np.random.random(a.size)
>>> b
array([ 0.00673736,  0.90089115,  0.31407214,  0.24299867,  0.7223546 ])
>>> np.lexsort((b,a))
array([0, 3, 2, 4, 1])
>>> a.argsort()
array([0, 2, 3, 4, 1])
>>> a[[0, 3, 2, 4, 1]]
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 3])
>>> a[[0, 2, 3, 4, 1]]
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 3])
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit of a hack, but if your array contains integers only you could add random values and argsort the result. `np.random.rand` gives you results in `[0, 1)` so in this case you're guaranteed to maintain the order for non-identical elements.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([0,3,1,1,1])
>>> np.argsort(arr + np.random.rand(*arr.shape))
array([0, 4, 3, 2, 1])
>>> np.argsort(arr + np.random.rand(*arr.shape))
array([0, 3, 4, 2, 1])
>>> np.argsort(arr + np.random.rand(*arr.shape))
array([0, 3, 4, 2, 1])
>>> np.argsort(arr + np.random.rand(*arr.shape))
array([0, 2, 3, 4, 1])
>>> np.argsort(arr + np.random.rand(*arr.shape))
array([0, 2, 3, 4, 1])
>>> np.argsort(arr + np.random.rand(*arr.shape))
array([0, 4, 2, 3, 1])
```

Here we see index `0` is always first in the `argsort` result and index `1` is last, but the rest of the results are in a random order.

In general you could generate random values bounded by `np.diff(np.sort(arr)).max()`, but you might run into precision issues at some point.

Comment: Isn't it too big an assumption to assume the vectors contains only integers?

Comment: Well, I don't I know. I was going on what was given in the question and it is acknowledged in my answer. Your solution is neat though.