# Find the index of the k smallest values of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

In order to find the index of the smallest value, I can use `argmin`:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1, 7, 9, 2, 0.1, 17, 17, 1.5])
print A.argmin()     # 4 because A[4] = 0.1
```

But how can I find the indices of the **k-smallest values**?

I'm looking for something like:

```
print A.argmin(numberofvalues=3)   
# [4, 0, 7]  because A[4] <= A[0] <= A[7] <= all other A[i]
```

*Note: in my use case A has between ~ 10 000 and 100 000 values, and I'm interested for only the indices of the k=10 smallest values. k will never be > 10.*

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-to-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array), especially the second answer there, for the best solution to this (it's O(n) - full sorting the entire array is not absolutely necessary).

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33623184/

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Use [`np.argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html). It does not sort the entire array. It only guarantees that the `kth` element is in sorted position and all smaller elements will be moved before it. Thus the first `k` elements will be the k-smallest elements.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1, 7, 9, 2, 0.1, 17, 17, 1.5])
k = 3

idx = np.argpartition(A, k)
print(idx)
# [4 0 7 3 1 2 6 5]
```

This returns the k-smallest values. Note that these may not be in sorted order.

```
print(A[idx[:k]])
# [ 0.1  1.   1.5]
```

---

To obtain the k-largest values use

```
idx = np.argpartition(A, -k)
# [4 0 7 3 1 2 6 5]

A[idx[-k:]]
# [  9.  17.  17.]
```

WARNING: Do not (re)use `idx = np.argpartition(A, k); A[idx[-k:]]` to obtain the k-largest.
That won't always work. For example, these are NOT the 3 largest values in `x`:

```
x = np.array([100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0])
idx = np.argpartition(x, 3)
x[idx[-3:]]
array([ 70,  80, 100])
```

---

Here is a comparison against `np.argsort`, which also works but just sorts the entire array to get the result.

```
In [2]: x = np.random.randn(100000)

In [3]: %timeit idx0 = np.argsort(x)[:100]
100 loops, best of 3: 8.26 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit idx1 = np.argpartition(x, 100)[:100]
1000 loops, best of 3: 721 µs per loop

In [5]: np.alltrue(np.sort(np.argsort(x)[:100]) == np.sort(np.argpartition(x, 100)[:100]))
Out[5]: True
```

Comment: Any idea how this handles ties?

It seems if you want random tie break the only possible way is to use lexsort which sorts the whole array. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20199459/1993389

The partition docs say introselect is not stable, but I'm not sure if this means ties are broken at random.

Comment: @user27182: Per [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html), if `a` is an array with fields (i.e. a [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.rec.html)), then you can either specify an `order` or let the unspecified fields be used to break ties. So if you pour `A` into the first field of a structured array, then pour random (tie breaking) numbers into a second field, then `np.argpartition` could be used to select the `k` smallest (or largest) with random tie breaks.

Comment: Keep in mind that the first `k-1` elements are not guaranteed to be in order from smallest to largest.  If that's something you need, you could use `np.argpartition`, slice the array using the first `k` indices, and then use `np.argsort` on the resulting array.

Answer (score 34):

You can use [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) with slicing

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([1, 7, 9, 2, 0.1, 17, 17, 1.5])
>>> np.argsort(A)[:3]
array([4, 0, 7], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thanks! But wouldn't it be very slow to have to compute *all* the `argsort` and then keeping only the k (<=10) first values?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the implementation of `argsort`. Specifically, if it is implemented as a generator, and depending on the actual sorting algorithm it could potentially be lazy, or it could sort the entire set first I'm not sure.

Comment: From the other comments, it does seem that `argsort` sorts the entire set, so I would prefer one of the other suggested solutions that use `argpartition`

Comment: This nice thing about this solution (compared to `argpartition`) is that we can guarantee that the k indices we are looking for are in ascending order.

Answer (score 6):

For **n-dimentional arrays**, this function works well. The indecies are returned in a callable form. If you want a list of the indices to be returned, then you need to transpose the array before you make a list.

To retrieve the `k` largest, simply pass in `-k`.

```
def get_indices_of_k_smallest(arr, k):
    idx = np.argpartition(arr.ravel(), k)
    return tuple(np.array(np.unravel_index(idx, arr.shape))[:, range(min(k, 0), max(k, 0))])
    # if you want it in a list of indices . . . 
    # return np.array(np.unravel_index(idx, arr.shape))[:, range(k)].transpose().tolist()
```

Example:

```
r = np.random.RandomState(1234)
arr = r.randint(1, 1000, 2 * 4 * 6).reshape(2, 4, 6)

indices = get_indices_of_k_smallest(arr, 4)
indices
# (array([1, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int64),
#  array([3, 2, 0, 1], dtype=int64),
#  array([3, 0, 3, 3], dtype=int64))

arr[indices]
# array([ 4, 31, 54, 77])

%%timeit
get_indices_of_k_smallest(arr, 4)
# 17.1 µs ± 651 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: I was looking for an answer for the n-dimensional cases, and your's worked as expected! Additionally, it's a fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.partition(your_array, k)` is an alternative. No slicing necessary as it gives the values sorted until the `kth` element.

Comment: This puts the element at index `k` (possibly unsorted) in sorted position. Since the sorted position is not necessary index `k` or `k-1`, we cannot guarantee that `your_array[:k]` contains the `k` smallest elements after `numpy.partition`.

Comment: This is the best answer for values of the array (not indexes) in Oct. 2019.  @protagonist I don't understand your comment.   Please correct me if wrong, but evidence that this partition function works correctly is to run the following in a loop:  y = np.arange(10) ; np.random.shuffle(y) ; y.partition(3) ; assert y[:3+1].max() < y[3+1:].min()   ... did the partition function have different behavior in old numpy version or something?  Also FYI:  `k` is zero-indexed.