# Finding k-smallest values of 2D tuples according to their second index

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I need to find k-smallest values of tuples according to their second indexes in python, 
for example i have a list of tuples that contain distance of some points from the fix point, like : `[('p1',12.5),('p2',3),('p4',1),('p5',16),('p6',15),...](from fixed point p0)`  and i want to find k-smallest values according to distances.

I mean something like this code, which is explianed here : [Find the k smallest values of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226400/find-the-k-smallest-values-of-a-numpy-array)

I would appreciate for your solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `heapq.nsmallest`, and specify the second element in the tuple as the comparison key:

```
from heapq import nsmallest 

lst = [('p1',12.5),('p2',3),('p4',1),('p5',16),('p6',15)]
nsmallest(3, lst, key=lambda x: x[1])
# [('p4', 1), ('p2', 3), ('p1', 12.5)]
```