# Perform numpy argparition on tuples

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I have a list of tuples. Each tuple holds two things:

```
1. A distance
2. A topic name
```

Now I want to find out the`k` smallest distances from this list. The list size is very big and `k` is quite small (`k <= 5`).

I think `numpy.argpartition` would have an edge instead of just sorting the entire list. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34226816/5672613) describes how to perform `argparition` on an *1-D* array.

For example, let's say we have the following:

```
L = [(0.5, 'Anime'), (0.3, 'Arduino'), (0.7, 'Chess'), (0.1, 'Coffee'), (0.9, 'Space')]
A = np.asarray(L)
```

Now if `k = 3`, then after performing `argparition`, we should have the following `indices` array:

```
idx = [1 3 0 2 4]
```

And so `print(A[idx[:k]])` would give:

```
[(0.1, 'Coffee'), (0.3, 'Arduino'), (0.5, 'Anime')]
```

The above was a simulation that I want to achieve. But given that I have a tuple, how can I perform `argparition` based on the first element of each tuple (i.e. the distance)?

Comment: does it work? what is the question? would it make sense to sort the array (or list for that matter) so this can be performed efficiently?

Comment: I added the question before describing the scenario. I've added the question now at the last.

Comment: I don't know why it is being downvoted. I've clarified the question and added a scenario that I want to achieve. Please tell me if I've worded the question poorly.

Comment: @RichieV, I have explicitly mentioned in the question that the size of list is big and ``k`` is small. So I think sorting wouldn't be the most efficient approach here. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand if you tried anything. But the following works:

```
import numpy as np

L = [(0.5, 'Anime'), (0.3, 'Arduino'), (0.7, 'Chess'), (0.1, 'Coffee'), (0.9, 'Space')]
A = np.asarray(L)

print(A[np.argpartition(A, 3, axis=0)[:,0]][0:3])
```

Where you get:

```
array([['0.1', 'Coffee'],
       ['0.3', 'Arduino'],
       ['0.5', 'Anime']], dtype='<U32')
```

Is that the solution you were looking for? the second element is in no use in this case at least.