# How would you find the the indexes of the k lowest elements in each row of a matrix with no looping?

Tags: python, numpy

The indexes of the k lowest elements of an array can be found using np.argpartition as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226400/find-the-index-of-the-k-smallest-values-of-a-numpy-array), I can only think of applying this to many rows using a loop. Is there a way that this can be done without a loop, using some kind of matrix operation?
I would like a resulting matrix where each row contains k indexes (of the k lowest elements).

Comment: Just use the `axis` argument in the `argpartition` function and it will perform the operation along that axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to worry about having to use loops in NumPy. All such operations are [broadcastable](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#:%7E:text=The%20term%20broadcasting%20describes%20how,that%20they%20have%20compatible%20shapes.&text=NumPy%20operations%20are%20usually%20done,element%2Dby%2Delement%20basis.). If you want to apply the op to a matrix and have each row containing k lowest elements, use `np.argpartition(matrix, axis=-1)`