# Insert elements from one matrix into another at specific indices numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a matrix

```
A = np.zeros((n,n))
```

with say n=4. I have another matrix

```
B = np.array(
    [7, 3, 5, 4],
    [4, 3, 2, 1],
    [6, 7, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
)
```

First I need the indices of the smallest k elements (e.g. 2) in every row of `B`, in this case it would be

```
np.array(
    [1, 3],
    [3, 2],
    [2, 3],
    [0, 1]
)
```

I can do this doing `np.argsort` but that ends up sorting the whole array, `np.argpartition` can sort the first k elements but I need a way to get the indices. Lastly I want to insert the smallest k values of `B` into `A` at the indices giving the matrix

```
A = np.array(
    [0, 3, 0, 4],
    [0, 0, 2, 1],
    [0, 0, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 0, 0]
)
```

What's a possible way to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the index of the k smallest values of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226400/find-the-index-of-the-k-smallest-values-of-a-numpy-array)

Comment: It answers the first part of the question about getting the indices of the k smallest values, I need the last part which inserts the values at those indices in `B` into `A`.

Comment: Have you tried `A[indices] = B[indices]`? I'm not sure but it may be as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
n = 4
A = np.zeros((n,n), dtype=np.int32)
B = np.array([[7,3,5,4],[4,3,2,1],[6,7,4,5],[1,2,3,4]])

indices = np.argpartition(B, 2, axis=1)[:,:2]
values = np.take_along_axis(B, indices, axis=1)
np.put_along_axis(A, indices, values, axis=1)
print(A)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 3, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```