# How to get the indices of x smallest elements in a large numpy matrix/multi-dimensional array (works for any number of dimensions)?

Tags: numpy

Given a large numpy matrix/multi-dimensional array, what is the best and fastest way to get the indices of the x smallest elements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the index of the k smallest values of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226400/find-the-index-of-the-k-smallest-values-of-a-numpy-array)

Comment: No, that question is about a 1-dimensional array. This question is about a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

```
from typing import Tuple

import numpy as np


def get_indices_of_k_smallest_as_array(arr: np.ndarray, k: int) -> np.ndarray:
    idx = np.argpartition(arr.ravel(), k)
    return np.array(np.unravel_index(idx, arr.shape))[:, range(k)].transpose().tolist()


def get_indices_of_k_smallest_as_tuple(arr: np.ndarray, k: int) -> Tuple:
    idx = np.argpartition(arr.ravel(), k)
    return tuple(np.array(np.unravel_index(idx, arr.shape))[:, range(min(k, 0), max(k, 0))])
```

This answer gives the correct indices, but those indices aren't sorted based on size of the elements. That's just how the introselect algorithm works, which is used by `np.argpartition` under the hood, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect.

It would be nice if the return was also sorted based on the size of the elements, ex. index 0 of the return points to the smallest element, index 1 points to the 2nd smallest element, etc.

Here's how to do it with sorting. Keep in mind that sorting the results after `np.argpartition` is going to be much faster than sorting the entire multi-dimensional array.

```
def get_indices_of_k_smallest_as_array(arr: np.ndarray, k: int) -> np.ndarray:
    ravel_array = arr.ravel()
    indices_on_ravel = np.argpartition(ravel_array, k)
    sorted_indices_on_ravel = sorted(indices_on_ravel, key=lambda x: ravel_array[x])
    sorted_indices_on_original = np.array(np.unravel_index(sorted_indices_on_ravel, arr.shape))[:, range(k)].transpose().tolist()
    # for the fun of numpy indexing, you can do it this way too
    # indices_on_original = np.array(np.unravel_index(indices_on_ravel, arr.shape))[:, range(k)].transpose().tolist()
    # sorted_indices_on_original = sorted(indices_on_original, key=lambda x: arr[tuple(np.array(x).T)])
    return sorted_indices_on_original


def get_indices_of_k_smallest_as_tuple(arr: np.ndarray, k: int) -> Tuple:
    ravel_array = arr.ravel()
    indices_on_ravel = np.argpartition(ravel_array, k)
    sorted_indices_on_ravel = sorted(indices_on_ravel, key=lambda x: ravel_array[x])
    sorted_indices_on_original = tuple(
        np.array(np.unravel_index(sorted_indices_on_ravel, arr.shape))[:, range(min(k, 0), max(k, 0))]
    )
    return sorted_indices_on_original
```